# AWS/Python: Peeking SQS message

Tags: python, amazon-sqs

There is a receive function at https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sqs.html#SQS.Client.receive_message to get SQS message,

Is there a function that I can just take a Peek at the SQS messages, without actually receiving it. Because If I receive the messages, it will be deleted from the queue. But I want the messages to be stay in the queue after peeking.

Answer (score 1):

you can check
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-visibility-timeout.html

aws sqs sdk's (and client libraries written on top of them) by default they dont delete messages. but they have 'Visibility Timeout' which is 30 seconds by default. That means after you read the message , it wont be visible to other consumers for 30 seconds. It is up to a client to delete it within that time frame so that no one else will get that message ever.

So You can reduce that visility time out to something really small like  1 second. So you can download the message and within 1 second it will be available to other consumers . you can even set it to 0 so everyone can read the message at any point.

But this still means you will receieve the message. SQS is pretty simple queue system. you might want to check other queue system like **Kafka** or different way to design your system like using Notification services such as **SNS**